# Ошибка при активации бота для музыки дискорд(бот на пайтоне)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\semyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\semyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\semyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'vc' is not defined
```

Такая ошибка при активации бота с помощью `;play` (у меня такой префикс и команда), `ffmpeg` работает.

Вот код на воспроизведение музыки

```
    @bot.command() async def play(ctx, arg):
            global vc
        
            try:
                voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
                vc = await voice_channel.connect()
            except:
                print('Уже подключен или не удалось подключиться')
        
            if vc.is_playing():
                await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, музыка уже проигрывается.')
        
            else:
                with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                    info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)
        
                URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        
                vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\Windows\System32\ffmpeg.exe",
        source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
                        
                while vc.is_playing():
                    await sleep(1)
                if not vc.is_paused():
                    await vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: global vc - ошибка тут.

Comment: а как решить это?

Comment: я убрал global vc теперь ошибка discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vc' referenced before assignment